# Why Java Scene Builder is not showing the exact Background color when the program runs

Tags: java, colors, javafx-2, fxml, scenebuilder

I have made a window, some buttons and a textfield in Scene Builder.

**In Scene Builder:** [image]

But when I run my program via netbeans or double clicking on the .jar file, its runs fine but just the color does not show. Background becomes white. And specially the textfield, I created it dark color, it also becomes white. You can understand my problem if you check the secreenshots.

**After running the program:**
[image]

There is no error in my code. I do not understand why it is happening so. It supposed to show the exact color which is defined by me. Can anyone help me?

You can also see my fxml code here http://pastebin.com/1sif2Dsq

Comment: Can you include FXML file in your question?

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected, you forgot to save your file after changing style. In my `SceneBuilder` it looks exactly as on 2nd picture. Save your `FXML` file before exporting your project to `jar` file.

Also, as a sidenote. Consider to use some layout manager instead of `AnchorPane` which uses absolute positioning for your components.

Comment: I saved all the things. But nothing is changed.